# Code fragment from java to typescript

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, nativescript

Don't understand how to structurize this java code to work in typescript(javascript):

```
channel.join().receive("ok", new IMessageCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Envelope envelope) {
        System.out.println("JOINED with " + envelope.toString());
    }
});
```

Code found here: https://github.com/eoinsha/JavaPhoenixChannels

Was thinking about something like this:

```
var phoenix = (org as any).phoenixframework.channels;
var callback = new phoenix.IMessageCallback({
    onMessage: function (arg) {
        console.log('callback');
    }
});

channel.join().receive("ok", callback);
```

It compiles successfully and no errors are thrown, but I don't get my callback when I join the channel.

Any insights appreciated!

**-- UPDATE**
Turns out I was doing it correctly, problem in connection lied elsewhere, thanks all who pitched in! :)

Comment: @Weedoze the user is consuming a Java/Android library through JavaScript/TypeScript API, as is common in NativeScript

Comment: @Weedoze with NativeScript you can access Java libraries and using marshaling you can write JavaScript code using the same libraries. You can also do the same with the Objective-C API for iOS.

Comment: does the arg in function gives data? mine is working and the function is called but no data or null in arg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement a Java interface you can use the following syntax.

```
var clickListener = android.view.View.OnClickListener({
    onClick: function (view) {
        // Do something on click
    }
});
```

You can refer to the [documentation article](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/overview.html#dynamic-class-generator) about android runtime and the data conversion techniques

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add to Nick Iliev's answer

The correct way to extend the interface in question is the following

```
var callback = new org.phoenixframework.channels.IMessageCallback({
    onMessage: function (arg) {
        console.log('callback');
    }
});
```

You need to specify the full class name, that includes package + class name (org.phoenixframework.channels + IMessageCallback)

Comment: Can you confirm that you followed all instructions correctly up to the attaching of the callback? Can you also verify that a connection is indeed established with the backend?